# Code 31 (Windows cannot load the drivers) For Some Portable Devices

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, device-manager, windows-10-v1511

I have 3 physical USB drives.

A) Flash drive

B) Physical external drive (self powered)

C) Physical external drive (wall powered)

**All but one of the partitions on these drives exhibits the yellow exclamation**:

```
This device is not working properly because Windows cannot load the drivers required for this device. (Code 31)

Object Name not found.
```

Looking down the log I can see the following error (DriverFrameworks-UserMod:10110 then 10111) related to the partitions that have the issue:

```
A problem has occurred with one or more user-mode drivers and the hosting process has been terminated.  This may temporarily interrupt your ability to access the devices.
---
The device External (location (unknown)) is offline due to a user-mode driver crash.  Windows will attempt to restart the device 5 more times.  Please contact the device manufacturer for more information about this problem.
```

The **only partition that doesn't exhibit the error is the only logical partition** - all others are primary partitions.

The **drives are available fine** to windows explorer and background services (such as the backup software)

They all show up as **HEALTHY in Disk Management**.

The **issue can be solved by restarting the machine**. "Scan for hardware changes" or "Update driver software" (software is already up to date) don't help.

This **problem is intermittent** (maybe after waking up from sleep). The only reason it bothers me is that if I try to remove these portable devices when they are in this error mode I will get a blue screen.

If I **try to restart the machine or gracefully eject one of the USB partitions** in this conflict state I get a BSOD, and WhoCrashed tells me cbfltfs3.sys is to blame.

**How can I try to determine the cause of the problem?**

Windows 10 Pro x64, 1511, 10586.164

Comment: Why the downvote without a comment?

Comment: Sounds like a Sleep Resume issue, also called Windows Hell.

Comment: Yes, it might come on only after a sleep resume cycle... I will keep an eye on it.